# Split a dataframe into multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe; I split it  using groupby. I understand this splits the dataframes into multiple dataframes. How can I get back those individual dataframes , based on the groups and name them accordingly? So if said df.groupby(['A','B'])
and A has values A1, and B has values B1-B4, I want to get back those 4 dataframes callefdf_A1B1..df_A1B1, df_A1B2...df_A1B4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by `locals` but not recommend

```
variables = locals()
for i,j in df.groupby(['A','B']):
    variables["df_{0[0]}{0[1]}".format(i)] = j
df_01
Out[332]: 
   A  B              C
0  0  1  a-1524112-124
```

Using dict is the right way

```
{"df_{0[0]}{0[1]}".format(i) : j for i,j in df.groupby(['A','B'])}
```

Comment: Thank you very  much. What is the best way to write these individual dataframes to excel,, keeping the excel name same as dataframe name?

Comment: @Victor something like `
'd={"df_{0[0]}{0[1]}".format(i) : j for i,j in df.groupby(['A','B'])}'


'for x, y in d.items():
    y.to_csv(x + '.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

Offering an alternate solution, using [pandas.DataFrame.xs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and some [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) magic -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a1', 'a2']*4,
    'B': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']*2,
    'val': [i for i in range(8)]
})

df
#    A   B  val
# 0  a1  b1    0
# 1  a2  b2    1
# 2  a1  b3    2
# 3  a2  b4    3
# 4  a1  b1    4
# 5  a2  b2    5
# 6  a1  b3    6
# 7  a2  b4    7

for i in df.set_index(['A', 'B']).index.unique().tolist():
     exec("df_{}{}".format(i[0], i[1]) + " = df.set_index(['A','B']).xs(i)")

df_a1b1
#        val
# A  B
# a1 b1    0
#    b1    4
```