# Get separate dataframes from a dictionary of dataframes Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary `d` full of a collection of dataframes:

```
key     type          size       value
gm1     dataframe     mxn        ....
gm2     dataframe     mxN        ...
..
gm10    dataframe     nxM        ...
```

I want to output these dataframes one-by-one using their `keys` as the names of the new dataframes. I try doing this first by iterating over the keys of the dictionary:

```
for key in d.keys():
    key = d[key]
```

This gives me the output of the last dataframe `gm10` and obviously names it `key` because it simply updates the name as key rather than naming the output dataframes as their keys.

Is there an easy way to get `gm1`, `gm2`,....`gm10` each as their own named dataframes?

Comment: You can but not recommended , this will need `locals` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077811/split-a-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes/54078036#54078036

Comment: You can already access the dataframes with `d['gm1']` ... `d['gm10']`, which is way more versatile than finding a dynamic way to refer to them as `gm1` ... `gm10` in your code.  Is there a reason why you must have them the latter? It might help answer your question better to understand the background.

Answer (score 0):

This is the dictionnary

`d={}`

To get the dataframes' names & print the list of names

```
listing=list(d)
print(listing)
```

Loop through the dataframes'names

& get the dataframe one-by-one

& print the dataframe one-by-one

```
for l in listing:
 df= d[l]
 print(l)
 print (df)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, this only prints the information but does not allocate the data into a dynamic object