# Dynamically capture the values in loop while creating a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

While creating the dataframe, I would like the year and month value to get captured in the variable. For example, for first pass, dataframe name should be df_2019_1 and so on. Any suggestions would be appreciated !!!

```
year = [2019]
month = [1,2,3]

for year in year:
  for month in month:
      df_year_month = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: try with locals ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S: Sorry I am new to Python, what do you mean by locals?

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077811/split-a-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes/54078036#54078036

Comment: Accessing locals directly is really not recommended, even by the poster of the answer - which i realise is you :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access names like this in python, but you can store them in a dictionary, also `year in year` is overriding.

```
years = [2019]
months = [1,2,3]

df_dict = {}

for year in years:
  for month in months:
    df_dict[(year, month)] = pd.DataFrame()

print(df_dict[(2019, 1)])
```

p.s. this is written in your syntax but consider List/Dict comprehension here